# How do I see the results of unique records added after adding records to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a PHP noob.

I have a database that I will update weekly with a CSV. So far I've managed to upload the file to the server, open the file with PHP, and insert the data in my table.

Now I want to return the unique records that were added (on screen or in a file). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes them unique? We need a little more information about your schema.

Anyway, you can easily add a `date_added` column that defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you could run a query that sorts the `date_added` descending to find out what was added.

With regard to only pulling unique results.. well, you shouldn't be re-inserting a unique row, so if you correctly avoid doing that, then the `date_added` will only reflect truly new entries.

Here is a code sample:

First, add the `date_added` column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will take care of using the current date automatically, so you do not have to change anything about your existing `INSERT` code.

With this column in place, you can now easily check which records were added for a specific date:

```
-- Rows for March 29, 2010
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE(`date_added`) = '2010-03-29';
```

The `DISTINCT` will make sure you only see unique rows that were added on that date.

Here's another handy query, which will pull "today's records":

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE(`date_added`) = CURRENT_DATE;
```

The only thing you need to remember is that existing records will have a date of 0, since the column did not exist at the time of their inserts.

Comment: Thanks Matt.

There is only one column in the database, so each record is unique.

Comment: @billy I see.. that's simple enough then. See my edit for a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting the new rows with a timestamp, you can do something like this

```
// Insert CSV into the DB with this timestamp
$todays_insert_time = time();

...

// Get unique rows from today
$unique_rows = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `whatever_column_makes_the_row_unique` FROM `some_table` WHERE `insert_time`=" . $todays_insert_time);
```